# Mogoose can not connect DB , and no any error display

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I don't know why , all the logs just show connecting...

no error , no success.

which way I should go to check?

thanks

there is the code..

```js
var db = mongoose.connection;
 db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
 db.once('open', function() {
   console.log("connect");
 });




 mongoose.connection.on('connecting',function(){
  
        **//only here be printed**
  console.log('db connecting ');
 })

 mongoose.connection.on('connected',function(){
  console.log('db connected');
 })


 mongoose.connection.on('disconnected',function(){
  console.log('db disconnected ');
 })

 mongoose.connection.on('close',function(){
  console.log('db close ');
 })

 mongoose.connect(config.uri,config.options);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this -

Install NPM dependencies:-

1.mongodb-uri

2.mongoose

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uriUtil = require('mongodb-uri');

var connect = function() {
    mongoose.connect(uriUtil.formatMongoose(YOUR CONFIG URL));
};
connect();

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.log);
db.on('disconnected', connect);
```

thank you

Comment: but my code is running very good until today morning ... It's suddenly show this bug...

Answer (score 0):

I check mongoDB logs

> 2017-04-11T19:06:33.786+0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:39514 #4657 (30 connections now open)
>   2017-04-11T19:06:33.788+0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:39516 #4658 (31 connections now open)
>   2017-04-11T19:06:33.789+0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:39518 #4659 (32 connections now open)
>   2017-04-11T19:06:33.790+0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:39520 #4660 (33 connections now open)
>   2017-04-11T19:06:33.790+0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:39522 #4661 (34 connections now open)
>   2017-04-11T19:06:33.795+0800 D COMMAND  [conn4657] run command owserver.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
>   2017-04-11T19:06:33.795+0800 I COMMAND  [conn4657] command **owserver**.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:178 locks:{} 0ms

it's seem mongoose already connected , but I still can't use mongoose find({}).exec(), when I call that, the application have no any of callback;

=====================

already fixed

I remove the node_module/mongoose

then use cnpm reinstall

bug gone.